Is there a standardized way to get data inside my Dynamic Gutenberg Block?
I'm building a featured posts block. I'd like to have a 1:1 preview of the rendered front-end in my editor, so that the experience isn't disconnected.
I have my basic block setup, attributes are correctly passed up/down from render.php to edit.js, and so on. Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation that would tell me:

Where it's best to fetch this data, and how - I'd assume in the edit.js file, which executed on a certain event, but should I use a query, an effect? I need to fetch the data before I render this thing - is a check enough? And so on.
If there is an automated way to fetch it already, and -
If it's officially supported.
How to not duplicate calls. For example, it would be nice if I just had a function I could call both on the front-end (through a REST endpoint, I guess?) and on the back-end, so that I don't have to duplicate logic.

I'm aware you could quite literally just write a fetch, but perhaps I missed something about this standard, because the "Gunteberg Block Handbook" didn't really mention it.
In essence, is there a standardized way of fetching data for Blocks, and if not, what's a good approach?

After reading through a lot of documentation/discussion, I found that the "official" way of requesting data for a block is useSelect. In my case, the answer would be:
const posts = useSelect(select => {
    return select("core").getEntityRecords("postType", "post", {
        per_page: 3,
        sticky: true
    });
});

